# How to set GET POST and REQUEST strings dynamically

Tags: php, post, dynamic, get, request

Okay So for awhile I have been attempting to set GET POST and REQUEST variables dynamically.

I store the variables I want it to get or post or request inside an sql table. each variable has it's own column. In this same row it records the type I want it to try to use(GET,POST,REQUEST). I am telling you this so you see how I want to go about doing this.

**Source**

```
$snmpbq=$os_DB->query("SELECT * FROM `spiders` WHERE site = '".$site_name."'") or die(mysql_error());
$num=$os_DB->num($snmpbq);
if($num == 1)
{
//get row as an associative array
$pb=$os_DB->fetch($snmpbq);
//data request type
$req_type = $pb['net_req_type'];
$a1       = $pb['a'];
$b1       = $pb['b'];
$c1       = $pb['c'];
$d1       = $pb['d'];
$e1       = $pb['e'];
$f1       = $pb['f'];
if($req_type == "get")
{
    $a   = $_GET[$a1];
    $b   = $_GET[$b1];
    $c  = $_GET[$c1];
    $d = $_GET[$d1];
    $e  = $_GET[$e1];
    $f   = $_GET[$f1];
}
```

Comment: when this runs it does not put the dynamic var in the get var. what did i do wrong or can this be done?

Comment: I know that this works cause i use it elsewhere in the script in a different way. instead of setting a get post or request i use it to set nvp arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this in a much cleaner way by replacing the blocks with 1 block... rather then checking the request type.

If you remove all your blocks and replace with:

```
$a   = $_REQUEST[$a1];
$b   = $_REQUEST[$b1];
$c  = $_REQUEST[$c1];
$d = $_REQUEST[$d1];
$e  = $_REQUEST[$e1];
$f   = $_REQUEST[$f1];
```

As per the PHP Documents [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

The variables in $_REQUEST are provided to the script via the GET, POST, and COOKIE input mechanisms and therefore could be modified by the remote user and cannot be trusted. The presence and order of variables listed in this array is defined according to the PHP variables_order configuration directive.

Comment: WORKS!!!! Thank you so much for posting an answer to this. this has been driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$result = 'someDataBaseQueryResult';
$$result = 'cool'; // now $someDataBaseQueryResult === 'cool'
```

Comment: Warning
Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.

Comment: See Nathan Hammond's example to get a better understanding of the comment above. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit confusing, but you could take this to the nth degree.

Idea for the sample code:

```
$sReq = $pb['net_req_type'];

foreach($pb as $key => $value) {

    if($key == 'net_req_type')
        continue;

     ${$key} = $_GET[$value];

}
```

It's a little late, and I'm a little drunk, but I think that may be close.  Haven't executed it though...